# how to build maven module with external jars included in the module-java

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven module with one pom.xml. I have added some external jars which don't have maven repository as external jars in the  project build path. The module is working fine(no errors).

When I am building it using maven build, it says some of package names from external jars are not found. there are many like this. the reason is corresponding packages API (groupid,artifactid) are not part of the pom.xml.

I want to know how to build maven module in such scenarios.

Appreciate any help

Comment: What do you mean by 'external jars in the project path'. What did you actually do?

Comment: i mean in build path on eclipse

Comment: You need to edit your question, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven does not support using jars that are outside of Maven. You have two choices:

1. mvn install:install-file
2. mvn deploy:deploy-file

The first puts the jar in your local repo, the second in your shared repo manager, which you should have.

Comment: Thanks, you mean, I am actually trying to build on eclipse tool. could you please help me further on this. mvn install:install-file command is for placing a single jar in local repository? can I the groupId or artifactId can be anything or it should be exactly same as package name or any other rule?

Comment: OK, what if someother person want to build the same module on their machine with the same code. these external jars will not be there in neither their local repository or the build path. do they need to do the same job by installing the file again?

Comment: I have tried using install-file, it installed jar to local repository, then I should to add an entry into pom.xml to refer the same right? if that is the case how does this pom.xml will work on other user machines?